# Using the AltBeacon library without extending Application

Tags: android, android-context, altbeacon

I have an Android Application that among other things monitor beacons using the **AltBeacon** library.
My problem is that, from my understanding, to have a class monitoring beacons you must make this class extend Application. But I already have a class extending Application.

Now I cant make my other class not extend Application and I cant make my "**beaconClass**" extend this class.

My only option is to find a way to use the **AltBeacon** library without extending Application.

So I would like to know if this is even possible and is there any way I could achieve this.

Comment: Why can't you extends the existing application? Is it one you made?

Comment: @cyroxis It is not the one I made. I do not have the right to extend it from the main developer of the app.